# Why does my <br /> tag show as an [object Object] when my javascript is rendered?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need to add break tags in between my sentences but when I do that I get [object Object] in place of a line break.  Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

```
const openingText = 'We\'re happy to hear your project is underway. '
 + <br /> +   'You can review this business to tell others about your experience.';
```

Example in browser:

[image]

Example in dev tools:

[image]

When I write it like this I get a syntax error:

```
const openingText = (
  <>
      We're happy to hear your project is underway.
      <br /><br />
      You can review this business to tell others about your experience.
  </>
);
```

[image]

When I add the br tags inside of the quotes it just thinks it's regular text:

```
const openingText = 'We\'re happy to hear your project is underway. <br /><br />' + 
  'You can review this business to tell others about your experience.';
```

[image]

Comment: the <br /> should be included the string

Comment: In your code example above, the <br/> tag isn't in quotes, so Javascript is going to try and interpret it. Try adding the <br/> tag as a string: ex: ` "<br/>" `

Comment: Yes, I find it confusing that you're using React for a <br> in a JS string, is there any reason for this?

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error. What browser are you using?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, React is a JS library that they are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you can't add a `string` and an `Object`:

```js
var tmp = {}
console.log('This is an object: ' + tmp)
```

What you want to do with React is:

```
const openingText = (
    <>
        We're happy to hear your project is underway.
        <br />
        You can review this business to tell others about your experience.
    </>
);
```

If you get an error using that syntax, you're probably on an older version of react or using a tool that doesn't support [React Fragment short syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html), in which case you should be able to do:

```
const openingText = (
    <React.Fragment>
        We're happy to hear your project is underway.
        <br />
        You can review this business to tell others about your experience.
    </React.Fragment>
);
```

Comment: well, you can add a string and an object, it's just that the object will be converted to a string using its valueOf method prior to the concatenation. (:

Comment: I edited my original post to show you what happens when I do this.  I get a syntax error :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to either use : [dangerouslysetinnerhtml](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const str = 'We\'re happy to hear your project is underway.<br />You can review this business to tell others about your experience.';

    return ( 
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{__html: str}} >

      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Or use template literals :

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const str = `We're happy to hear your project is underway.
You can review this business to tell others about your experience.`;

    return ( 
      <div style = {{ whiteSpace: 'pre-line'}} > 
        {str} 
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```