# How to add a line break inside a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am passing a javascript variable which contains the address and has multiple strings in one sentence. So while setting the variable, I want to break the sentence in 2 lines, i.e. streetNumber and streetName should be in first line and city and zipcode in second line. So I am trying to break the line using `<br>` tag like this:

```
let addr2  =  inputDataState.addressDetails.addrObj.street.streetNumber + ' '
             + inputDataState.addressDetails.addrObj.street.streetPrefixCode 
             + inputDataState.addressDetails.addrObj.street.streetName+ ' ' + <br /> 
             + inputDataState.addressDetails.addrObj.street.streetSuffixCode + ' ' 
             + inputDataState.addressDetails.addrObj.street.city + ' ' 
             + inputDataState.addressDetails.addrObj.street.zipCode ;
```

But instead of a line break, I am getting `[object Object]` . So how do I add the line break to divide the variable in 2 lines?

Comment: To add line breaks in a string, use a template literal multi-line string, or use `\n`.

Comment: I have tried \n and <br/>, its taking the whole string .I mean <\n is coming up .NEw line is not getting added.

Comment: can you post your jacascript variable

Comment: If you're getting `[object Object]`, then one of those properties is not a `string` but an object. Also, `<br />` is not wrapped in quotes `""`

Comment: Worth mention, that it's React/JSX code

Comment: @pranami https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54934604/why-does-my-br-tag-show-as-an-object-object-when-my-javascript-is-rendered?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 1):

insert "\n" in your variable which you are using to print.

Example

```
let streetName ='Madhapur, Hyderabad \n India-500081';

console.log(streetName );
```

will print this like below

```
Madhapur, Hyderabad 
India-500081
```

Just add '\n' where you want to break the line.

```
let addr2  =  inputDataState.addressDetails.addrObj.street.streetNumber + ''
             + inputDataState.addressDetails.addrObj.street.streetPrefixCode 
             + inputDataState.addressDetails.addrObj.street.streetName+ '\n ' +  
             + inputDataState.addressDetails.addrObj.street.streetSuffixCode + ' ' 
             + inputDataState.addressDetails.addrObj.street.city + ' ' 
             + inputDataState.addressDetails.addrObj.street.zipCode ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first is the newline character ( \n ). The newline character creates line breaks within the output of a string, be it simply text or JavaScript-generated HTML.

```
 inputDataState.addressDetails.addrObj.street.streetNumber + ' '
 + inputDataState.addressDetails.addrObj.street.streetPrefixCode 
 + inputDataState.addressDetails.addrObj.street.streetName+ ' ' + '\n'
     + inputDataState.addressDetails.addrObj.street.streetSuffixCode + ' ' 
     + inputDataState.addressDetails.addrObj.street.city + ' ' 
     + inputDataState.addressDetails.addrObj.street.zipCode ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another variable so you don't have to type so much and interpolate with [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
let inputDataState = {
  addressDetails: {
    addrObj: {
      street: {
        streetNumber: '123',
        streetPrefixCode: 'S.',
        streetName: 'Main',
        streetSuffixCode: 'St.',
        city: 'Springfield',
        zipCode: '95123'
      }
    }
  }
};

const x = inputDataState.addressDetails.addrObj.street;
let addr = `${x.streetNumber}
${x.streetPrefixCode}
${x.streetName}
${x.streetSuffixCode}
${x.city}
${x.zipCode}`;

console.log(addr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Object_destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) and [Template_literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to solve your problem and make the code cleaner

```
const {
  streetNumber,
  streetPrefixCode , 
  streetName,
  streetSuffixCode, 
  city,
  zipCode
} = inputDataState.addressDetails.addrObj.street

let addr2 = `${streetNumber} ${streetPrefixCode} ${streetSuffixCode}
${streetSuffixCode} ${city}  ${zipCode}`
```

Test this

```js
console.log(`${6+2} 
is 
equal 
to
${2*4}`)
```